# iphone UIPicker default position

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

Is there a way to set a default position for a UIPicker?  I mean, if the user has the option of selecting any number from 1 to 100 in the UIPicker, can I set it to automatically start at 50?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` like this:

```
[somePickerView selectRow:49 inComponent:0 animated:NO]; // Zero-indexed, so row 49 is the row that says 50
```

You can fire it in the `viewDidLoad` method for the `UIViewController` managing the view which contains the `UIPickerView`.

(It could also be that you can specify the default value in Interface Builder, but I'm not sure and I didn't check...)

Comment: When I add this, I don't get any type of error in the code - but the Picker is completely blank.  When I comment out this line it goes back to normal - weird.

Comment: Very weird indeed... You're sure the picker view is fully loaded before you're calling `selectRow:inComponent:animated`?

Comment: I'm using iOS 7 - how do you know when the Picker is loaded? It seems that 'viewDidLoad' is called prior to 'viewForRow'...